# jQuery - Loop through Label/Input pairs and add unique ID

Tags: jquery, loops

I have the following code placed multiple times across a page some in a table and some in a tooltip:

```
<p class="radioBtn">
    <label for="business"></label>
    <input id="business" type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="" />
</p>
<p class="radioBtn">    
    <label for="private"></label>
    <input id="private" type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="" />
</p>
```

I would like to know how, with jQuery I can loop through the entire page and add a unique ID number on to the end of the label 'for' attribute and also the input 'id' so I would end up with something unique for each pairing like this:

```
<p class="radioBtn">
    <label for="business0"></label>
    <input id="business0" type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="" />
</p>
<p class="radioBtn">    
    <label for="private0"></label>
    <input id="private0" type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="" />
</p>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a 1:1 ratio between `input` and `label` elements?

Comment: @David yes there is. Eventually the pairs will be added from a database so there could up to 100 pairing at any given time. The 'for' and 'id' must match as I am using JS to change their appearence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late answer, but using jQuery, I'd probably do it more like this:

```
$("input:radio[name=radioBtn]").attr('id',function(index,id){
    $(this).prev()[0].htmlFor += index;
    return id += index;
});
```

Less code and likely better performance.

To explain, [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) can accept a function for the value you're setting. Its return value will be the new value of the attribute.

In the function, the first parameter is the index of the current item in the iteration, the second parameter is the current value of the attribute being set (the `id` in this case).

So the function body goes like this:

- `$(this).prev()` Get the previous element using [jQuery's `.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- `[0]` Pull the DOM element out of the jQuery object. *(the `<label>`)*
- Set the label's `htmlFor` property to `+=` the current index.
- Return the current id `+=` the current index.

Comment: thanks for this, an excellent answer. I don't fully understand understand point 2. Pull the DOM element out with [0]. Can you explain a bit further please?

Comment: @mtwallet: A jQuery object is a collection of DOM elements, plus a bunch of methods. You can access those elements by index via `[]` (square bracket notation), just like you would with an Array. So with `$(this)`, you have an object containing the `radio`. With `.prev()`, the object contains the element before the `radio`. With `[0]` you retrieve that element from the jQuery object (at index 0). Now that you have a native DOM element, you can use the native `htmlFor` property where you can just do `+=index` instead of having to call `.attr('for')` once to get the `for` and again to set it.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, that makes perfect sense. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$('label').each(function(index) {
    var forAttr = $(this).attr('for');
    $next = $(this).next();
    if($next.attr('id') == forAttr) {
        $(this).attr('for', forAttr + index);
        $next.attr('id', forAttr + index);
    }
});
```

Though it would be better to do this on the server side.

Comment: I wonder if you can explain what is going on here so I can learn a bit from it. I understand how you are looping through the elements but what is the 'index' part of the function?

Comment: @mtwallet, `index` is just the number of the element in the set we're currently looping through. First label has an index of zero, second has one etc. Take a look at the manual: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function(){
    $("input:radio[name='radioBtn']").each(function(index){
        var currElem = $(this);
        var prevLabel = currElem.prev();
        currElem.attr("id", this.id + index);

        prevLabel.attr("for", prevLabel.attr("for") + index);
    });    
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HTyLY/)

Comment: many thanks this works great as well. Can you please explain what the 'index' part of the function is doing?

Comment: `index` will get the current iteration index for the `.each()` function